# What are my rights as a Greek Citizen married to Irish Citizen, for living in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, greek-citizens

I am a Greek Citizen, married to an Irish Citizen and I'm wondering what my rights are for living and working in the UK?

My husband has just moved there for work and I'm not sure if I have the right to join him and if I would have to get a visa.

Comment: This belongs on [Expatriates.SE], but the short answer is that you need to apply for [a visa for which the fee is currently £1,538 for up to 2 years and 9 months plus a health care surcharge of  £1,560 for 2 years and six months or £1,872 for 2 years and 9 months](https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa).  After that I think you'll need to pay these fees again to renew for another 2.5 years before you can apply for indefinite leave to remain but I'm not certain of the details.

Comment: The rules of the **Common Travel Area** applies only to British and Irish citizens. They do not apply to the family members who are 3rd country nationals. The spouse (or family members) of an  Irish citizen will be treated in the same way as those of a British citizen (i.e. the same rules apply). *The CTA was developed to facilitate the principle of free movement for British and Irish citizens between the UK, Ireland and the islands and to ensure that British and Irish citizens continued to benefit from a mutual enjoyment of rights.*

Comment: See https://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/government_in_ireland/ireland_and_the_uk/common_travel_area_between_ireland_and_the_uk.html for an explanation

Comment: Was your spouse born in Northern Ireland? There are special EUSS rules that apply to the family members of a 'person of Northern Ireland'.

Comment: @MJeffryes those special rules apply only if the family member is "not from the EU, Switzerland, Norway, Iceland or Liechtenstein": https://www.gov.uk/settled-status-eu-citizens-families/family-member-eligible-person-from-northern-ireland

Answer (score -1):

You will need to lodge an application with the Spouse/Civil Partner of Irish National Scheme using [the instructions on their website](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/my-situation-has-changed-since-i-arrived-in-ireland/spouse-civil-partner-of-irish-national-scheme). You will need to provide evidence of your marriage, as well as your passports, evidence of your joint address, evidence of financial means (The Irish national earned €40,000 in the last 3 years over and above any State benefits), etc.

In regards to your rights to live and work in the UK, their website states:

> If you are married to, or in a civil partnership with, an Irish
> national you may be given permission to live in Ireland with your
> spouse/partner. If you are given permission on this basis you will be
> allowed to live and work in Ireland without the requirement for an
> employment permit.

and

> Please note **there is no automatic right to live in the State following
> your marriage/civil partnership to an Irish national.** If permission is
> granted, it is on the basis of sufficient evidence of a valid and
> genuine marriage/civil partnership and cohabitation.

Comment: The first quote is introduced by "In regards to your rights to Live and work in the UK, their website states..." The following text, however, does not address the OP's question about living in the UK, but only addresses the non-EU marriage partner's right to live and work _in Ireland_.

Comment: In **Ireland**, the spouse of a UK citizen will be treated as would a spouse of an Irish citizen. [De facto partner of an Irish or non-EEA national - Immigration Service Delivery](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/my-situation-has-changed-since-i-arrived-in-ireland/de-facto-partner-of-an-irish-or-non-eea-national/): *That person is called the eligible sponsor and can be an Irish national, a non-EEA national legally resident in the State **or a UK national living in Ireland**.*